# Using the locative case with "з"

Tags: відмінювання, граматика

So a friend recently came up asking me about this sentence:

> ". . . Геґрід з величезних бобрових унтах . . ."

What does 'з' mean here? would it mean the same as 'у' in this context: "Геґрід у величезних бобрових унтах"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *"з"* here is clearly a typo.

Victor Morozov's [localizaion](https://coollib.com/b/437573-dzhoan-ketlin-roling-sbornik-quotgarri-potter-7-knig-quot/read) of "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone", Chapter 11, reads the following (highlight mine):

> Почався листопад, а з ним і великий холод. Гори довкола школи стали скидатися на брили сірої криги, а озеро виблискувало, як сталь. Землю щоранку вкривала паморозь. *Із горішніх вікон було видно, як Геґрід **у** довгій шубі з кротячого хутра, кроликових рукавицях і **величезних бобрових унтах*** старанно обчищав на полі для квідичу обмерзлі мітли.

Comment: Weird typo, should I delete this one or keep it here just for the sake of it?

Comment: @ЛугеУшчимі, I believe the SE engine wouldn't let you delete your post once it received an (positively-voted?) answer. You can try, but don't be upset it it won't let you to.